# Patching the source to Support Older Devices (AOSP)

Tags: android, android-source

So I got an old (rather historic) Android device. It can't be build properly, neither AOSP or CM, because the device needs patching. So there's no way CM will roll official builds for it.

There were a bunch of developers that worked on it for a while, but they left (even the ones that worked on devices that had the same hardware).

Each time a new version of android arrives, the patches seem to change. So my question is: Can anyone help me understand the concept of patching the source now that Android N is so close to be released?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that your **old, historic** device meets android N hardware requirements?

Comment: The dev who was before managed to patch it for the N preview 4